# How do major attributes like agility compare to minor attributes like versatility

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I am having hard time choosing my gear like for example: what is better, item with +1 agility or +2 versatility? Both attributes translate to increase in damage...
[image]
[image]

[image]

**How do major attributes like agility compare to minor attributes like versatility?**

Comment: As a general rule, your spec's primary attribute directly affects your damage/healing.  I say spec because some classes have different primary stats based on their spec.

Comment: @Powerlord they both do, versatility is increasing the damage and so does agility... therefore there should be a way to express `agility*x = versatility*y`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a long time now, Blizzard has tried to make it so that primary stats completely trump secondary stats, and that in effect means item level trumps everything. They did not completely succeed (whether that is good or bad is a matter of opinion).

For players who do *not* wish to run challenging content (Mythic raids, High M+ keys), this rule of thumb should be enough to progress the character.

The conversion of a stat into its effect changes based on level. [According to the wiki](https://wow.gamepedia.com/Combat_rating_system), conversions for BFA are as follows:

```
+-----------------+--------------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|     Rating      |       Effect             | Level 60 | Level 70 | Level 80 | Level 85 | Level 90 | Level 100 | Level 110 | Level 120 |
+-----------------+--------------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Critical strike | 1% crit chance           | 8.5      | 9.71     | 11.18    | 12.02    | 12.94    | 15.07     | 17.62     |        72 |
| Haste           | 1% haste                 | 8.03     | 9.17     | 10.56    | 11.35    | 12.22    | 14.23     | 16.64     |        68 |
| Mastery         | 1 Mastery point          | 8.5      | 9.71     | 11.18    | 12.02    | 12.94    | 15.07     | 17.62     |        72 |
| Versatility     | 1% dmg/heal 0.5% dmg red | 10.03    | 11.47    | 13.2     | 14.19    | 15.28    | 17.79     | 20.80     |        85 |
+-----------------+--------------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Furthermore, at Level 120, 1 stamina converts to 20 hp.

This, however, doesn't *really* answer your question, and it is not really answerable in general form. For each class and specialization, theorycrafters come up with the "best" stat distribution.

[According to Noxicc, stat weights for feral druids are as follows](http://www.noxxic.com/wow/pve/druid/feral/stat-priority/):

> Agility [9.06] > Haste [7.56] > Mastery [6.06] >= Crit [5.68] >= Versatility [5.31]

**Which means 1 agility is worth ~1.7 versatility for feral druids at level 120**.

Those are however *generalized* results, intended to work for most item levels, talents and trinkets. depending of what *exactly* you are wearing, what type of encounter you are up against etc., this might vary.

You can get more accurate *quantitative* stat weights for your class & specc by using a good simulation software, such as Raidbots or Simcraft. Both are excellent tools to find out which gear pieces are better, considering your current gear, specialization, talents and even artifact traits (azerite traits for BfA).

Gear in WoW is complex enough that there is no single answer to "what piece of gear is better".

Rules of thumb:

- If you do not wish to do challenging content, primary stats are better than everything else. Just use the items with the highest item level (with the correct armour type for your class, e.g. leather for druids, cloth for warlocks etc.)
- If you do raiding (normal, heroic) and low-level M+ keys, stick with the stat priorities the guides (e.g. from Icy Veins, Noxicc, WoWHead or else) suggest
- If you want to push mythic raids or high M+ keys (25+ end of Legion), use a proper simulation tool to find out which piece of gear is better for what situation (e.g. AE vs ST, M+ vs raids).

Comment: If you want to make proper use of these stat distributions you can use the addon Pawn. This calculates the stats on the fly and shows them in the item tooltips (gear, bag, loot window, etc).

Comment: @dly Pawn does not do anything itself. you feed it a pawn string with stat weights. per default, Pawn uses stat weights from a guide, which is option #2, but if you *really* want to optimize your stats, you still need to sim your char, and then take the stat weights you get from the sim and feed them into pawn. Most sims can export their results as pawn strings to make that easier.

Comment: I know... but nonetheless Pawn is a good addition. Just don't use the Noxxic stats. They're mostly bad. Sim it for yourself and feed that into Pawn.